# Find count of a column in pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using below method to find count of a pandas dataframe having 55k rows. This is included in a for loop of site list (4000 sites). It is taking many minutes to complete the loop of 4000 sites when below line is included.

```
for i in g_sitelist:
   x = len(dfreglist[(dfreglist['site'] == i) & (dfreglist['isactive'] == 1)])
```

Is there any other better way to do so that the loop can be completed with in a second.

Comment: Please add a small sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
site_counts = dfreglist[dfreglist['isactive'].eq(1)]['site'].value_counts()
```

This would give a series of the `site` values and the count that are active which you can then iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy - convert each column to array and call `np.sum`:

```
m = (dfreglist['isactive'].values == 1)
for i in g_sitelist:
   x = np.sum((dfreglist['site'].values == i) & m)
```

Faster solution:

```
df = dfreglist[dfreglist['site'].isin(g_sitelist) & (dfreglist['isactive'].values == 1)]

out = df['site'].value_counts()
```